# What does the percentage indicates next to update rollout in new Manage release page in Playstore

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console

Playstore app publish console has introduced new page Manage releases instead of APK page, here we all manage app's apk for different environment like alpha,beta and producation.

In the Manage Production i have rolled out an new update for existing app after publishing the app i could see two option for the release "Halt rollout", "Update rollout" and next this there is symbol which shows 5%, on clicking the update rollout everytime the percentage symbol get incremented by 5%.

I may like to know what does the percentage symbol indicates?

Comment: I think it's percentage of your users who gets the new update.

Comment: i dont think so, when i uploaded the app it will take minimum couple of hours to reflect in live, within that i have got 10%.

Comment: "You can release an app update to production using a staged rollout. With a staged rollout, your update reaches only a percentage of your users, which you can increase over time.", from [Developer Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en&ref_topic=7072031)

Answer (score 8):

In order to make the app available for all our users, then rollout percentage should reach 100.

For this we need to click the update rollout which initially increments to 5 percent then to 10 and then 25 so finally when all increments done it will reach 100, by this time only it will available to all users else it will be available to only few percentage of users,

Comment: So, in case of new installs, will user get the latest version (which is rolled out to 50% for instance) on his mobile or the older version?

Comment: Why does the percentage not automatically increment. I have to manually do this every morning? Confused here why does it not go up by 10% each day? Or is that a daft question to be asking for automation.

Comment: @MehrozeYaqoob Users will get old version if they are not part of the rollout